# How to get a list of Google Slide Title and Slide Number - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I am looking to get a list of all slide titles and respective slide numbers from an existing slide deck of 50+ slides.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742236/getting-title-of-slide-in-google-apps-script) however it has been posted a couple of years ago and doesn't work any more.

I am grateful for any guidance on how to get started on solving this problem.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample Slides and the output values you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information. And also, can I ask you about the detail information of `however it has been posted a couple of years ago and doesn't work any more.`?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike for example if I have 5 slides with a title that says A, B, C, D, E and the respective slide numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - the on running the script I have two columns on a spreadsheet that give the title and respective slide number. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike when I used the below - I get the following error ```Exception: Object is not of type Shape. (line 8, file "Code")``` would you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the answerer might be thinking the solution now. So how about waiting for the answere's response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
function somethingWithSlides(){

var slidesArray = [];

var presentation = SlidesApp.openById("XXXXX");

var slidesLength = presentation.getSlides().length;
var slidesTitles = presentation.getSlides().map(function(slide){return slide.getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString()});
var slidesIds = presentation.getSlides().map(function(slide){return slide.getObjectId()});

  for(var i=0;i<slidesLength;i++){
    slidesArray.push([slidesTitles[i],slidesIds[i]]); 
  }

return slidesArray; 

}
```

If not, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @timmer for your quick response. I am getting the below error on running the code ```Exception: Object is not of type Shape. (line 8, file "Code")``` Would you know what this means?